# Windows Form dies right after the constructor is done

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm currently writing an IRC bot/client and I have stumbled upon a small problem. Every channel is to be displayed in a separate window with its own set of controls. I have created an appropriate window class ChanWindow:

```
public partial class ChanWindow : Form
{
    string Chan;
    string Username;

    IRCBot Caller;

    public ChanWindow(string channame, string uname, IRCBot caller)
    {
        Caller = caller;
        Caller.Join(channame);
        InitializeComponent();
        Chan = channame;
        Name = Chan;
        Username = uname;
    }

    //various functionalities required for window use
}
```

I'm storing the window objects in a `ConcurrentDictionary<string, ChanWindow>`, because there is (supposed to be) a separate thread sending appropriately edited messages to windows. They are all initialized in a loop:

```
 foreach (string chan in Chanlist)
 {
     Chans[chan] = new ChanWindow(chan, Name, this);
     Chans[chan].Show();
 }
```

Where `Chanlist` is a `List<string>` of channels to join.
Having witnessed the windows die shortly after the program starts, I put a breakpoint in the line `Username = uname;` of ChanWindow constructor and noticed it being tripped immediately before the window's death.

My main question is: what is the cause and how can I avoid it? Is using a Dictionary a good idea? Should I build some sort of wrapper/container class which would handle the window's functionality?

Comment: Does any thread except the main write to the UI?

Comment: Tell me if I'm wrong, but don't you need to do something like `Channs[chan].Show()` too?

Comment: @DanPichelman I have it planned, though they don't have a chance to do so since the window dies before anything happens.

Comment: @ArnoSluismans And so I do. I omitted this line... I don't know why. Fixing it now.

Comment: I think is a bad idea doing too much stuff inside a form constructor... it would be better to override OnLoad, then you are sure that child controls are initalized and layout done...and the problem is that the constructor is throwing an exception... you should use a try catch block to handle it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect you don't have

```
Application.Run(new ChanWindow());
```

in your main entry point (`Program.Main()` by default).

If you don't make the main GUI thread `Show` the form, and wait for it to close, nothing will stop the thread from completeing and your application closing.

---

If you want to start the message loop independently you will still need to call [`Application.Run()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.run.aspx) so the main thread will start handling events. If you call it without a parameter the message loop won't stop automatically so you'll have to call `Application.Exit()` explicitly when you want the message loop to stop. Then the main thread will then continue to the end of the program and end.

You could just do this to your code,

```
 foreach (string chan in Chanlist)
 {
     Chans[chan] = new ChanWindow(chan, Name, this);
     Chans[chan].Show();
 }

 Application.Run();
```

but, if you want to automatically exit the application you could inherit your own `ApplicationContext`, as outlined in the [already linked MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157901.aspx), and pass that to `Application.Run()`, that is what its for after all.

Comment: Seems like this is indeed the case. This is my first Windows Forms project and the starting point was a console application anyway.
Do I need to create some sort of a super-window? Since whenever I call `Application.Run(Chans[chan])` after creating a new window, the program doesn't progress until I close it.

Comment: Once you call `Application.Run` the main thread will only respond to events. The program won't continue until `Application.Exit` is invoked implicitly or directly. You can do any code you like between `Form.Show()` and `Application.Run()` but until it is called, the message loop doesen't start and event handling doesn't begin.

Comment: For your situation, where I assume you want the application to close automatically when you close the last form, look at making your own `ApplicationContext` and passing that to `Application.Run()`, an example is behind the link.

Comment: In other words, I will need to delegate work to other threads before calling it?
Either way, thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @HaxtonFale, you could pass the work into the constructor of the form.

Comment: I could, though I'd rather not multiply threads. If a client is in multiple channels, he's still receiving a single stream of messages which then need to be distributed among channel windows.

Comment: @HaxtonFale The message loop only runs on the main thread ... but I deviate from the question.